# Generate unique api keys for user in node js application for access to your apis

Tags: node.js, database, api, server, api-key

how to generate API Keys for the user of your nodejs application on the basis of different parameters of the user in the database for giving access to our server endpoints.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [randomUUID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/randomUUID) which is part of node's crypto module. Then you can take the generated uuid, hash it using [bcrypt](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js) and store it in db.

```
const saltRounds = 10;
const token = crypto.randomUUID();
const hashedToken = await bcrypt.hash(token, saltRounds);
```

And in subsequent requests, you can validate it like so:

```
const token = req.body.token // this is an example
bcrypt.compare(token, hashedToken, function(err, result) {
    // result == true
});
```

You can also store the creation date and use it to invalidate tokens if they've passed certain time.

Hashing the token protects it in case a malicious user/hacker was able to access the database. You can combine this solution with time
and scope restrictions then you'd have a pretty solid solution.

Answer (score 3):

When we talk about generating API keys, I always preferred to use uuid or crypto library.
To securing your keys, encrypt the keys before saving them into the database.
To encrypt the keys, you can use Google's Key Management Service (KMS) and JWT but I will prefer to use KMS.

Answer (score -16):

You can use different parameters to generate an API key and store it in the database for different users.

### Example :

1. You have the ***username*** and ***email*** of the user in the database.
2. Add Both Of them to make a new string and store it in a variable
3. Then convert it to ***Base64*** and store it in your database in apiKey column of the user.

### Code

```
data = req.body.email+req.body.username;
let apiKey = Buffer.from(data).toString('base64')
```

Update your database column of that user with this API Key which the user can use to access to your server endpoints.

Comment: That is very predictable, please do not use that.

Comment: We can keep any values in data which is unknown to the outside world!

Comment: It can get decoded. Please don't use this. Maybe calculate a hash and then do a Base 64 of that, but that isn't too secure either.

Comment: If that gets implemented then it can be reversed easily. You should not include data related to the user at all and it should consist of random numbers and letters upper case and lower case. Also, when storing them you shouldn't store them in plain text, you should hash them, that way if the database is compromised the API keys are hashed and cannot be used for a good period.